# Q&A: Clojure translated into Racket: rand-nth, keys and get

Tags: clojure, racket

How do you get a random element from a list in racket, the equivalent of Clojure 
`rand-nth`?

How do you get the key from a hash-map in Racket, the equivalent of Clojure `keys`?

How do you get the value corresponding to a key in Racket, equivalent of `get` from Clojure?

Comment: Do you mean hash tables or association lists? For hash tables, use `hash-keys` and `hash-ref`.

Answer (score 0):

This function will pick the random element:

```
(define (rand-nth list)
  (list-ref list (random (length list))))
```

This function will pick all the keys from a hashmap:

```
(define (keys array)
  (map car array))
```

This function will get the value if you give as arguments the hash-map and the key:

```
(define (get array k)
  (if (eq? (caar array) k)
      (car (cdar array))
      (get (cdr array) k)))
```